# Button to Map Android App

Tags: android, button, maps

I'm obviously new to app development but basically what I want to do is make a simple app that has a button called 'View Map' that, when pressed, will open up Google maps.

So far, I've coded an app with the 'View Map' button that simply returns some text below the button when pressed, which looks like this.

[image]

I have also made another app which uses the Google Developers' [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) to display a Google map when the app is opened.

My problem arises when I try to combine the two apps together. Instead of having it display just the button alone when opened, it displays both the button and the map in the home screen which looks like so:

[image]

and does nothing when the button is pressed.

What I've tried to do is use an OnClickListener that loads the map when the button is pressed, but that clearly ain't working. I assume it has something really basic to do with my activity_main class but I need help sorting it out so that the map isn't created immediately when the app is loaded.

My activity_main class looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="**My Key**"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View Map" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my MainActivity class looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button buttonMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
        buttonMap.setOnClickListener(mapListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener mapListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        }
   };

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Dan, I need to know more about what you're looking to do.    Do you want Google Maps to load inside your application, or do you want the actual Google Maps app to open up when the user clicks your button?  (Note that calling the actual Google Maps app involves some hacks that only work for US locations, last time I checked.)

Secondly, I see you're using MapActivity, which is part of Google Maps API v2 and is being deprecated by Google in favor of v3, which doesn't require an API key and would be accessed in JavaScript through a WebView.  Any reason you're using Maps v2?

Comment: Whoops NVM about MapActivity.  I guess they kept it around for Maps API V3, but I thought they were deprecating it too.  I actually implemented a JavaScript map inside a WebView in one of my projects because this was my belief. :-(

Comment: I want to use the Google Maps API inside my application only when the 'View Map' button is pressed. I've already made an app loads the API when the app is opened, however I can't figure out how to make it so that the API isn't used unless the 'view map' button is pressed. And I'm not gonna lie, the second part of your reply is hilarious, ha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think you need to use your MainActivity for the button, then set the button's OnClickListener to trigger another Activity which will extend MapActivity.  Your MainActivity will then extend Activity only.  Here's what your "mapListener" should consist of:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MyMapView.class);
// i.putExtra("key", "value"); // use this to give extra data to the new Activity
startActivity(i);
```

Define ctx as an instance variable (i.e. outside of any functions) in MainActivity and set it to "this":

```
Context ctx = this;
```

From within mapListener, "this" is the OnClickListener object itself, not the Activity, so using "this" in "new Intent()" will cause an error.  Since mapListener exists inside the Activity though, "ctx" can be seen just fine and its meaning won't change.

Everything inside "mapListener.onClick" should go into your new Map Activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: Consider your MainActivity, which extends Activity, as the one with the button on it.  Put the first block of code I wrote above into the button's OnClickListener, and the other line of code inside the class but outside any functions.  By making this new Intent, which starts your Activity class extending MapActivity, essentially your application now has two screens that you can go back & forth between using the Back button &  buttonMap.

Don't place the Intent code into the MapActivity.  Your MainActivity only contains the button w/intent and your MapActivity only has the map.